# Vue-Multiselect displaying object instead of "name" field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-multiselect

I would like to know how to change this vue-multiselect example shown at this link (https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-tagging), so that the array shown underneath only shows a list of names separated by commas.  You can see in the image, I have selected Javascript and Open Source...and beneath it shows the entire object for both.  I want to only show the 2 names separated by commas.  Any help would be appreciated...

[image]

Can I make a simple change (hopefully) to this {{ value }} call below to accomplish this?  Changing to {{ Value.name }}, etc does not work.

```
<div>
  <label class="typo__label">Tagging</label>
  <multiselect v-model="value" tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" placeholder="Search or add a tag" label="name" track-by="code" :options="options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="addTag"></multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to convert it using javascript in the binding:

```
<pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value.map(v => v.name).join(', ')  }}</code></pre>
```